# Rails 3 - Couldn't find <controller> without an ID

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have created a new controller and I added the a new action (**my_new_action**). To the routes.rb I added the route for this action, but when I set to the URL browser the address **localhost:3000/users/my_new_action**, I will get the error that is in the subject.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ....

  def my_new_action  
  end
end
```

Could anyone help me please, how to fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'my_new_action'
    end
  end
```

**EDIT2**
This is the exact output from terminal:

```
    Started GET "/users/my_new_action" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Nov 26 13:55:50 +0100 2011
  Processing by UsersController#my_new_action as HTML
filter_access_to tried to find User from params[:id] (nil), because attribute_check is enabled and @user isn't set, but failed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.0ms)
```

Comment: I doubt that's the exact error message you're getting - could you post the entire exception?

Comment: You've posted the exact problem..."filter_access_to tried to find User from params[:id] (nil), because attribute_check is enabled and @user isn't set, but failed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID"

Comment: So it is a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID)`. Your params[:id] is nil and the filter_access_to cannot find the user with id = nil...

Comment: But I want to the "my_new_action" page just have some text-information, how can I do it? I am a bit confusing from it

Comment: So the solution that fix the problem:

`filter_access_to :all, :except => : my_new_action`

Answer (score 2):

The title is misleading, you've put `<controller>` because you're probably seeing `User`, but it most likely refers to a model you're trying to build or use. Because you've not pasted more code I cannot say exactly where's the issue, but look for a reference to an `id` you are using in the code - that's most likely null.

Comment: well, I have only the empy action in my controller, there's just a definition of the action, my view for this action is empty too. I expected this is enough to create a new action... I don't want to use a reference to an ID... just crate a new "page" (+ I updated my question)

Comment: And in the update you have the error spelled out for you: `filter_access_to tried to find User from params[:id] (nil), because attribute_check is enabled and @user isn't set, but failed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: but how is then possible, that if I set the url **users/new**, everything works?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the route isn't working, what the code shows is that the url, /users/my_new_action, is trying to find a user id of '/users/my_new_action' for the default 'show' action.

I would replace the routes code you provided to something like (please not this is not tested code)...

```
resources :users do
    match '/my_new_action', :controller => 'users', :action => 'my_new_action', :as => :mynewaction
end
```